# Crosstab/Pivot in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table

I need to convert rows to columns in PostgreSql. It would be great if someone can put some shed on this. I tried to solve this using crosstab but no luck.

```
select *
from crosstab(
    'select
    count(distinct no_of_cars) as no_of_cars,
    car_type,
    month
from abc
group by 2, 3
order by 3',
    'select distinct month from abc order by month'
) as ct(
    no_of_cars text,
    car_type text,
    month text
)
```

Attached Screenshot of the data.
[image: Dataset]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer filtered aggregation, as I find that to be easier to maintain and understand:

```
select car_model, 
       sum(no_of_cars) filter (where month = 'Nov-22') as "Nov-22",
       sum(no_of_cars) filter (where month = 'Oct-22') as "Oct-22",
       sum(no_of_cars) filter (where month = 'Sep-22') as "Set-22"
from the_table
group by car_model
```

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name but month column can't be hard-coded as it will cause problem in handling future date..

Comment: @Raunak: there is no way you can make this dynamic. A fundamental restriction of SQL is that the number, types and names of all columns must be declared before the query is executed. You can't have a query that returns a different number of columns each time you run it. In general pivot/crosstab is much better handled in the application, not in SQL. An alternative is to aggregate this into a JSON structure